# How can I apply a shadow to a non-rectangular shape in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

Say I have a shape like this one[image: this one], created by using two separate views.

Is there a way to apply a uniform shadow outside of it, without the having the circle's shadow also show up on top of the rectangle?

I'm personally working with react-native-paper, and I've tried using Surface elements with

```
mode='elevated' elevation={5}
```

But obviously it gives a separate shadow to each of the shapes, rather than casting it only outside of the structure.

Comment: If you can make an SVG of your shape, that should work